# Selenium does not seem to recognize an overlay

Tags: selenium, webdriver, e2e-testing

I'm having trouble getting selenium webdriver to identify and click on any part of an overlay that is displayed when I navigate to www.oneplace.com. The overlay is meant to be dismissed when clicked. See below for my selenium code

```
IWebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
try {      
   wd.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
   wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.uk/);
   wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.oneplace.com/");
   wd.FindElement(By.Id("takeoverOverlay")).Click();

   if (!wd.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).Text.Contains("DONATE")) {
       Console.Error.WriteLine("verifyTextPresent failed");
   }
 }
 finally { wd.Quit(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you automate scenarios, automate what a user would do. What would a user do to close the popup? They would click on the X in the top right. Right-click on that element in your browser and choose Inspect (or whatever the variation is in your favorite browser). The element that is that X is

```
<img class="closeTakeover" ... src="http://cdn.salemweb.net/zcast/shared/close-btn.png?v=1">
```

So we can use code like the below to close it.

```
wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("img.closeTakeover")).Click();
```

A couple additional comments...

1. Why are you navigating to google and then to oneplace? You should be able to remove the first navigation?
2. I would suggest that you remove the implicit waits and only use explicit waits.
3. You don't really want to search the entirety of the page (HTML) text looking for DONATE. It could be in the name of some book or article and you log a pass when it should actually be a fail. Find the specific element that you expect (or don't expect) to contain DONATE and search only that element's text, e.g. the code below verifies that DONATE doesn't appear in the top nav section.

   ```
   if (!wd.FindElement(By.CssSelector("nav")).Text.Contains("DONATE"))
   ```

Comment: Hi Jeff, very much appreciate your answer and advice. Your solution works fine. These are just early days for me using selenium. Having said I think some of these overlays do not have an X at the right-hand corner. Also, a user is at liberty to dismiss the overlay in fastest convenient way possible. I'm kind of wondering is there any solution to the initial problem of just clicking on part of the overlay transparency to dismiss the overlay.

Comment: When you tell Selenium to click an element, it will click the center of that element. When the element is the size of the browser window and the center is generally where the popup is, you will have to "help" Selenium click where you want. You can do it using `Actions` and `MoveToElement` with an offset and click anywhere on the screen but you will have to do some calculations depending on where you want to click so you don't try to click off the screen or browser.

Comment: Jackpot. Thanks a lot for this Bro.